# SQL Server Connection Failed with Linux Mint + SQL Server 2008 R2 using AzureDataStudio

Tags: sql-server, openssl, azure-data-studio

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP4 database, however, I got this error and I have tried some solutions that I found here, but none works for me.

PS. I do not know exactly how to understand this error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>
> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
>
> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

I know the error is:

> SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error

My openssl version:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
built on: Mon Apr 20 11:53:50 2020 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-P_ODHM/openssl-1.1.1f=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

I have also tried to change my `openssl.cnf`:

1. Add this line at the beginning

   ```
    openssl_conf = default_conf
   ```
2. Add these lines at the end

   ```
    [ default_conf ]
    ssl_conf = ssl_sect
    [ssl_sect]
    system_default = ssl_default_sect

    [ssl_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
    CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
   ```

But I am still getting this error.

PS: I am using Azure Data Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tks all, for who is facing the same issue:
I Just downgrade the SSL to 1.1.1 and it works.

SQL server 2008 r2 SP3 should support 1.1.1g or 1.1.1f.

Below are the instructions to follow:

1. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t).
2. Fetch the tarball: `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz`
3. Unpack the tarball with `tar -zxf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1`
4. Issue the command `./config`.
5. `sudo apt install make gcc`
6. `make`
7. `make test` to check for possible errors.
8. Backup current openssl binary: `sudo mv /usr/bin/openssl ~/tmp`
9. Issue the command `sudo make install`.
10. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl`
11. Run the command `sudo ldconfig` to update symlinks and rebuild the library cache.

Assuming that there were no errors in executing steps 4 through 10, you should have successfully installed the new version of OpenSSL.

Again, from the terminal issue the command:

```
openssl version
```

Your output should be as follows:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

source(dif openssl version but same approach)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: thanks a lot! saved me hours or days maybe..

Comment: Also, you may do it without downgrading of openssl. Just need to set SECLEVEL= 0 and fix configuration file sections a little. My journey here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77812112/what-to-do-if-cipherstring-defaultseclevel-1-in-openssl-3-configuration-file   To be honest, it is dirty workaround and this problem should be be fix on DB side