# What to do if CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 in openssl 3 configuration file is not working

Tags: docker, openssl

I am trying to update a .NET 7 application which is hosted in Docker to .NET 8

Previously I was used Docker image with openssl 1.1.1 (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0).

In /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf I used following workaround for mssql connection:

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

But then I have updated base image of my dockerfile. (to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0). I have found, that openssl was updated to 3.0.11 in new container.

My workaround is not working anymore. Something was changed in configuration but I can't get, what exactly it was:

```
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man5/config.html
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html
```

May anybody explain, how to set tls1 by default with openssl?

This is stacktrace of original problem:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
  ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
```

Comment: One alternative... you may not like it, but you could always update your SQL Server. Support for TLS 1.2 has been built in since SQL Server 2016 but there have been service packs, cumulative updates and hotfixes available to provide the same for servers [all the way back to SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server). There's really no excuse for hacking `openssl.cnf` files to downgrade security by enabling deprecated and insecure TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution. Almost the same workaround, but for openssl 3.0.11:

```
sed -i '/\[openssl_init\]/a ssl_conf = ssl_configuration' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

echo "\n[ssl_configuration]" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && echo "system_default = tls_system_default" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

echo "\n[tls_system_default]" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && echo "MinProtocol = TLSv1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && echo "CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

This means, DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 switched to 0 and sections are restructured a little. After script applied, need to recheck content of configuration file:

```
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_configuration    # Section must be registered here

# I adding new section in the end of the file:

[ssl_configuration]
system_default = tls_system_default

[tls_system_default]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

Source: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/migration_guide.html and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/config.html

> The security strength of SHA1 and MD5 based signatures in TLS has been reduced.
> This results in SSL 3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and DTLS 1.0 no longer working at the default security level of 1 and instead requires security level 0.

Comment: This was MOST helpful and worked perfectly for me. Thanks Illia!